specific radius in bevel with blender
i've done modeling in solidworks and mastercam ,but want to move my skillset over to blender.  one area i've had a difficult time replicating is radius edges.   in other modeling programs, i can just choose the 2 edges, then 'radius' then put in the radius i want (ie .25) and it puts that circle as close to the corner as possible without going outside the lines, then trims out the corner to match the circle.
is something like this precisely possible as i'm drawing cad parts and need to have precision, i can't just drag the bevel until it 'looks good'
thanks for any pointers, the learning curve for blender is a dropoff cliff for me
addition:  DOH, the scale.  i forget these things, you should see some of the Echeresque things i make with arrays that haven't had scales and origins applied.   I'll mess with this more today and come back with issues.
update:
for inside radius this works great and it was indeed scaling, but for outside radius, i'm not sure what to do.  here's an example, i want the 19mm radius to connect to the points of the bevel and in each corner, and to 'puff it out' slightly.


Hello and welcome. For very precise measurements, blender is probably not the best recommendation

what do you think the limit of resolution is?  is .025mm unreasonable to expect?

I think you'll find some of the snapping options useful.  click on the magnate to turn on snap and then play around (learn) some of the options.  here I snapped a circle to two nearby planes, perhaps simulating something you want:



this seems to have potential, but how can i then trim my corners away so the circle becomes the new edge instead of the 90?  and i'm making 3d stuff so have to do this many times feels ick.   blender is super awesome and free, so i'm not expecting it to complete surpass a 20k cam program, but radii are super basic in modeling, i don't know why its so difficult

First of all, you do not need the Last Operator panel to enter precise values - you can do that "on the fly" while you are using the Bevel tool.
So if you select an edge and press Ctrl+B to bevel it, rolling the mouse wheel changes the number of segments. And if you want the offset to be 0.25, you can simply enter .25 on your keyboard.
However, if it seems that the bevel radius has the wrong size and does not match the expected value you entered, this is probably due to a scaling issue. The bevel offset is always in relation to the object's scale, not its dimensions.
In the following example, both cubes have the same dimensions: X = 0.5 m, Y = 1 m, Z = 2 m. They were both created from a default cube with an edge length of 2 m, but the left one now has a scale of X = 0.25, Y = 0.5, Z = 1 while the right one has a scale of X = Y = Z = 1 because I applied the scale with Ctrl+A > Apply > Scale. This resets the scale to be the default 1 (or 100%) in all directions while keeping the changed dimensions.

Now I bevel two edges on both cubes, I enter the value 0.25 while beveling to get this bevel radius. However, as you might already see in the screenshot below, the result is not the same on both objects.

Switching to Vertex Select mode now so that it is easier to see how far the beveled edges go. In the orthographic view you can see, the left object's bevel goes down 0.25 m in Z direction, but only 0.125 in Y direction. On the right object it is 0.25 m in both directions. The reason of course is simple: the left object's scale is  1 on the Z axis, and 0.25 m × 1 = 0.25 m but the Y scale is 0.5, so 0.25 m × 0.5 = 0.125 m.

Changing to the other side to see the bevel on the bottom edges, the resulting difference is even more: since the left object only has a scale of 0.25 in X direction, the bevel here is only 0.25 m × 0.25 = 0.0625 m while on the right object it is 0.25 m in all directions.

So, if you want to use the Bevel tool with correct values it is crucial that you apply the scale beforehand.
One more thing, your question sounded as if you did not want to round edges necessarily but rather corner vertices connecting two edges. You can do this with the Bevel tool as well. To do this just use the shortcut Shift+Ctrl+B in this case.


Have you tried using the Width value in the Bevel tool Last Operator panel that pops up in the lower left hand corner of the 3D viewport when you use the Bevel tool?
In that panel with Width Type set to the default Offset
and Shape at the default 0.500 the Width value will be the radius of the bevel.
In the example below the bevel radius is set to 0.3m.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.2/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bevel.html

i'll try this and see if it works out.  i might be asking the wrong question, but this is useful to know, my cam program must not be using 'offset' because when i put those numbers in i get a much different looking part between the 2 programs

@rxdeath ...or probably you have not applied the scale to your object in Blender?
